# Windows workflow foundation designer in client application

Tags: c#, .net, workflow, workflow-foundation

We have a set of application which allows us to make some data acquisition. We would like to add the possibility to the user to specify an action to do depending on some conditions.

Conditions can be mathematical or logical, and will be checked for every data we received on our application.

The available actions will be limited(we currently decide what we can do, but offer the possibility to the user to configure a little bit action). An example of action can be: "Send an email

I heard of the windows workflow foundation and I've some questions:

1. Can we offer to the end user to create with the GUI editor those flow? I mean edit the conditions and the action to take?
2. Can we give them a limited set of "action" to execute?
3. Can we "debug" the workflow to see if we have the expected end value with a specific entry?

Thank you

Julien

Answer (score 0):

Questions:

1. Can we offer to the end user to create with the GUI editor those flow? I mean edit the conditions and the action to take?

   *Yes, [Rehosting the Workflow Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489451(v=vs.110).aspx).*
2. Can we give them a limited set of "action" to execute?

   *Yes, you can define the set of activities (actions).*
3. Can we "debug" the workflow to see if we have the expected end value with a specific entry?

   *Yes, [Debugging Workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358745(v=vs.110).aspx).*

Comment: Great news thank you very much! Small question for the 3): is it only possible for "us" developer with visual studio or is it possible to debug when we use the rehosting of the workflow designer?